# Poisson process VS poisson law : what is the subtlety?

Tags: probability

I always heard that for rare event we always use Poisson process. Example : We know that at each minute, when have a mean of $3$ call. Therefore, $X$ is a poisson process, and if $X$ denote the number of call, then $$\mathbb P\{X=k\}=e^{-3}\frac{3^k}{k!}.$$

But now, in my course today, to stud rare event we used Poisson process. What is this new tool, I don't understand where to use it ? Could someone explain by example ?

[Law for rare event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Law_of_rare_events) By poisson distribution

[Law for rare event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) By poisson process

Comment: Please clarify the distinction you are trying to make.  A Poisson process is a random process which has a Poisson distribution.

Comment: I have the impression that both work for rare event : @herbsteinberg

Comment: Basically they are describing the same thing.  The Poisson process is a term used for random variables, while a Poisson distribution is the term describing its distribution.  For example: Let $X$ be the number of counts per minute of some process where the mean number of counts is $a$, the the density function $P(X=n)=e^{-a}\frac{a^n}{n!}$.  The distribution function $P(X\le n)=e^{-a}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a^k}{k!}$.  It doesn't have to be a rare event.  It is used for discrete events where there is no theoretical upper limit.